# Restructure objects based on their inner arrays duplicates

Tags: javascript

I have this array of tasks:

```
[
    { id: 54321, Task: 'Task 1', Topics: ["111", "222"]},
    { id: 667566, Task: 'Task 2', Topics: ["222"] },
    { id: 76889, Task: 'Task 3', Topics: ["333"] },
]
```

and I want to restructure it based on duplicate strings inside Topics,
So the result should be:

```
[{
  name: "111",
  id: [54321]
}, {
  name: "222",
  id: [54321, 667566]
}, {
  name: "333",
  id: [76889]
}]
```

basically topic names should become unique and tasks id should group under the topic's name

Comment: Have you try something. You can use a method from Array
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: This is not what JavaScript destructuring is about. Destructuring means assigning to a set of variables in an object/array pattern. I think you mean "restructure", which means changing the organization of an object.

Comment: The basic approach you should use for something like this is to create an object whose keys are the part that you want to make unique. So create an object that has topics as the keys.

Comment: And the overall structure of the code will be nested loops: Outer loop over the array of object, inner loop over the topics.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to create the desired structure, we create a map of topics, using the topic name as the key, then use Object.values() to get the result array:

```js
    
const tasks = [
    { id: 54321, Task: 'Task 1', Topics: ["111", "222"]},
    { id: 667566, Task: 'Task 2', Topics: ["222"] },
    { id: 76889, Task: 'Task 3', Topics: ["333"] },
]

const result = Object.values(tasks.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    for(let topic of cur.Topics) {
        if (!acc[topic]) acc[topic] = { name: topic, id: [] }
        acc[topic].id.push(cur.id);
    }
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response/solution!

Comment: Glad to be of help!